# tic-tac-toe while and ||

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

hi im 17 and trying to teach myself c++. For one of my first projects I am trying to write a tic-tac-toe game and play vs an AI. So the code im having trouble with is this

```
main() {

    char player, computer;

    while (player != 'x' || player != 'o' )
    {
        cout << "do you want to be x or o?";
        cin >> player;
    };

    if (player == 'x' ) computer == 'o';
    else computer == 'x';

    cout << "player is: " << player << endl <<  "computer is: " << computer ;
    cout << computer;
};
```

I get the message " do you want to be x or o?", but then I enter x or o and it keeps repeating the same 
question. I think it has to do with the while loop. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is this an eg from the text book?

Comment: Warning, you are checking player before you initialize it!
It is possible that player will randomly end up with the value 'x' or 'o' before the user is ever asked!  You MUST initialize variables before you use them.

Comment: CodingMastero this isn't, its just something i came up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop end condition is wrong, and you shouldn't check until you've asked once.

```
do {
    cout << "do you want to be x or o?";
    cin >> player;
} while (player != 'x' && player != 'o');
```

Comment: ok thanks, i was thinking of doing a do while, but wasn't sure

Answer (score 7):

```
char player, computer;

while (player != 'x' || player != 'o' ) {
```

First of all, `player` isn't initialized to anything, so it contains random garbage.  You shouldn't be reading from it.  At least initialize it to some known value.

Second, your condition will always be true.  Suppose that `player` is `'x'`.  That satisfies the condition `player != 'o'`.

You probably mean:

```
while (player != 'x' && player != 'o') {
```

Comment: ahh thanks, that clarifies it for me now, but what should i initialize player to and how would i do that?

Comment: In your case, you could just initialize it something that isn't `'x`' nor `'o'` (for example: `char player = 'a';`).  But using a `do-while` loop like StilesCrisis mentions would be better so that you check the `player` value only after you've written to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the conditional. What I think you mean is `while (player != 'x' && player != 'o')`, i.e. when `player` is neither x nor o.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( (player == 'x' || player == 'o') == false )
```

Comment: `== false`?  Eww.  That's what the `!` operator is for.

Comment: Why do you need to use == false in a boolean expression at all

Answer (score 0):

```
    char player = ' '; // always init variables
    while (player != 'x' && player != 'o' ) //exit if false, when player == x or == o
    {
        cout << "do you want to be x or o?";
        cin >> player;
    };
```